# In python3, how to make for loop get all files if input is dir or pick the file if input is a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3, If input is a directory, then it gets all *.xml files from it, if input is a file then how to make `for` loop use it?

```
>>> dirs="foo"
>>> for file in glob.iglob(r'{0}/**/*.xml'.format(dirs),recursive=True):
...    print(file)
... 
foo/b.xml
foo/c.xml
foo/a.xml
>>> dirs="foo/b.xml"
>>> for file in glob.iglob(r'{0}/**/*.xml'.format(dirs),recursive=True): #Here, how to make "file" to get foo/b.xml ??
...    print(file)
... 
>>>
```

I can do this with an `if` condition, but is there a way to do it inside `for()`?.

Comment: So if a file is the input, you want to do what with the `for` loop?

Comment: if its a dir, then I will do some file operation on multiple files, if input is a file, then I will do same operation on a single file.

Comment: In your example, if it is a `dir` then it finds all XML files in that `dir`; you expect to perform the same function on a single `file`?

Comment: The `for` loop would be the wrong place. `glob.iglob` conceivably *could*, but *doesn't*, try to identify `foo/b.xml/**/*.xml` with `foo/b.xml`, mainly because `**` only matches 0 or more *child* directories; it would never try to look *up* towards the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os, glob

if os.path.isdir(your_path_here):
    xml_files = os.path.join(your_path_here, '**', '*.xml')

else:
    xml_files = your_path_here

for file in glob.iglob(xml_files):
    # Do something
```

Comment: Glob on a specific file path just returns a list with that single file path, so this is safe whether or not your final file path uses wildcards

Comment: The `if/else` can be collapsed to a single `if` if you do `your_path_here = os.path.join...` instead of creating a new variable. I provide this method so that we're not re-using variable names, which not everyone likes to do